# Why is Redirect URL Fully Qualified in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Why does the [redirect URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-app) have to match completely?  Wouldn't matching at the domain level be sufficient enough for proper security?

What if I had hundreds of paths?

example urls:

1. https://myawesomesite.com
2. https://myawesomesite.com/account/profile
3. https://myawesomesite.com/games/fungame/points
4. https://www.myawesomesite.com/games/fungame/points

...

I would have to enter the 4 above redirect urls into my B2C app configuration.

Comment: Does your awesome app handle all authentication responses at the same endpoint (e.g. /oidc-signin)?

Comment: No.  Imagine I had 100 unique paths and 99 of them are authenticated.  A user could bookmark any of the 99 paths.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett if they hit a authenticated page it should redirect to B2C and back to that page.

Comment: [Follow up related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47577252/185123)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually discussed in [RFC 6819](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819) "OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations" sections [4.1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.1.5), [4.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.2.4) and [5.2.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.3.5).

> 4.1.5. Threat: Open Redirectors on Client
>
> An open redirector is an endpoint using a parameter to automatically
> redirect a user agent to the location specified by the parameter value
> without any validation. If the authorization server allows the client
> to register only part of the redirect URI, an attacker can use an open
> redirector operated by the client to construct a redirect URI that
> will pass the authorization server validation but will send the
> authorization "code" or access token to an endpoint under the control
> of the attacker.
>
> Impact: An attacker could gain access to authorization "codes" or access tokens.
>
> Countermeasures:
>
> o Require clients to register full redirect URI ([Section 5.2.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.3.5))."

[Section 5.2.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.3.5) talks about the cases where this may be too restrictive and purposes alternate solutions.

Often times, the `state` parameter can also be used to redirect deterministically as suggested by Chris. However, you have to ensure that such a solution also does not end up being an open redirector, so the `state` parameter will either need to be protected (e.g. encrypted/signed), or used in conjunction with cookies.

Comment: If I own the domain myawesomesite.com, and I have an open redirector that allows any redirect URL on that domain, how could an attacker monkey w/ the redirect uri?  It would still have to redirect to my domain.

Comment: A common case is where a redirect_url accepts some query parameters, which can be exploited by the attacker to redirect to their site. The threat model assume that the user agent is redirected "without any validation". What you are suggesting is some sort of constraints or validation. Azure AD tries to strike a balance with an approach that works for most cases, but still restricts wildcards and query parameters. (Note that these vulnerabilities still happen today, esp. in complex apps: https://www.google.com/search?q="open+redirect"+vulnerability&tbm=nws)

Comment: Thanks for editing my response spottedmahn. I only had mobile page last night, which doesn't seem to have full featured editor.

Comment: ah, "query parameters", good point!  thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: followup question about [using the state parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577252/using-state-parameter-in-azure-ad-b2c-susceptible-to-open-redirect-vulnerability)

Answer (score 12):

It is common (and easiest) for all authentication requests to contain two redirect URLs:

1. One (often known as *the reply URL*) that is passed in the "redirect_uri" parameter, which *must be* registered with Azure AD B2C, to which *all* authentication responses are returned from Azure AD B2C to the relying party application. An example of this is `https://www.myawesomesite.com/oidc-signin`.
2. Another (often known as *the return URL*) that is round-tripped in the "state" parameter, which *doesn't have to be* registered with Azure AD B2C, to which the end user is returned after the relying party application has handled the authentication response. An example of this is `https://www.myawesomesite.com/games/fungame/points`.

An authentication handler, such as [the ASP.NET Core authentication middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect), manages these redirect URLs for you.

For instance, when the authentication handler creates the authentication request, it encodes the currently protected URL (e.g. `https://www.myawesomesite.com/games/fungame/points`) in the "state" request parameter.

To ensure this URL isn't tampered with, the "state" parameter should be protected, using encryption or signing.

When the authentication handler processes the authentication response, assuming it is a successful response, it creates an identity cookie and redirects the end user from `https://www.myawesomesite.com/oidc-signin` to the originally protected URL in the "state" response parameter.

Comment: If "state" sends the user to another domain (e.g. same app in another geo-region) then the process repeats (IP redirects back to /oidc-signin of that geo-instance) but user does not have to provide credentials again (SSO), but must wait for the interaction to complete. As I understand it...