# Add variables to reply URLs in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to set the redirect_uri in Azure B2C. I have a language field in the Url like this:

```
https://mydomain/de-de/projects
https://mydomain/en-us/projects
https://mydomain/sv-se/projects 
https://mydomain/ar-sa/projects
...
```

and to be correctly redirected, I have to add all the possibilities to the B2C Reply URLs and I am only limited to 20 max.

Is there a way to add variables to the redirect_uri?
Something like:

> https://mydomain/:lang/projects

where ":lang" is a variable the could take any value. 
[image]

////////////////////////////////////

Solution

The tricky solution was to manipulate the state and inject it with the returned URL due to the fact that it will be sent back after the login/signup response. createLoginUrl() method:

```
let url = that.loginUrl
                        + '?response_type='
                        + response_type
                        + '&client_id='
                        + encodeURIComponent(that.clientId)
                        + '&state='
                        + encodeURIComponent((state) + 'url'  + returnedUrl)
                        + '&redirect_uri='
                        + encodeURIComponent(window.location.origin)
                        + '&scope='
                        + encodeURIComponent(that.scope);
```

so here I split the state with 'url' word so I can read it again after the response came.

> encodeURIComponent((state) + 'url'  + returnedUrl)

An important details redirect_uri, it should be the same origin:

> '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.origin)

and this URL should be added to the returned URL in Azure B2C application.

Now I can split it again in tryLogin() method:

```
const statePartsWithUrl = (parts['state'] + '').split('url');
window.location.href = statePartsWithUrl[1];
```

and it works perfectly.

////-------------------------------------

Edit : 1.2.2019

```
const statePartsWithUrl = (parts['state'] + '').split('url');
let state = '';
let returnedUrl = '';
if (statePartsWithUrl != null) {
  state = statePartsWithUrl[0];
  returnedUrl = statePartsWithUrl[1];
}
```

Here is the splitting of the state to read the information from it in method tryLogin(options)

Comment: Did you do this in a Javascript method?  I have been trying to find a way to access the "state" variable via the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions and have found no way to add in information that I could then use to apply different redirects and such. @SamySammour

Comment: Add the information to the state as I mentioned above with a splitter or something. 
+ '&state=' + encodeURIComponent((state) + 'url'  + ([your_data]))

Comment: the data you can split it later and read it from the state

Comment: please see my new edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah so as you found out, you can't currently add wildcards to reply URLs in B2C.

This may be due to security concerns defined in the [OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819).
In it, the suggested counter-measure against Open Redirect Attacks is to have the client register the full redirect URI.

There is also no way to create apps programmatically: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19975480-programmatically-register-b2c-applications.

So sadly the manual way is the only way at the moment. But be sure to go upvote the feature request on User Voice.

I actually even tried to manually edit an app via Graph Explorer:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version."
        },
        "date": "2018-01-08T12:00:00",
        "requestId": "208e7159-d459-42ec-8bb7-000000000000",
        "values": null
    }
}
```

As you suggested in the comments, one way to work around this problem would be to use a single static redirect URI and keep the language/culture in the state/a cookie, and then do the redirect to the language-specific version after the user is returned to the app.

Comment: I guess the solution would be is to set a static return_uri (which is the domain) and send the actual returned Url within the state as a json object and then redirect manually when the response came.

Comment: Oh hey that's a pretty good idea! You could also use a cookie for that :) I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: I guess the cookie is not required in this case because the state will be sent back completely with the Url. More work but achievable! :)

Comment: Round-tripping the return URL, which doesn't have to be registered with Azure AD B2C, in the state parameter is the common approach. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520604/why-is-redirect-url-fully-qualified-in-azure-ad-b2c/47527533#47527533) for more info.

Comment: Hello @juunas, I added the solution up there with the question. If you are interested you can take a look. Cheers!