# Create azure B2C which can reply to wildcard URL

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In our project we are using B2C where the front-end is hosted on a webapp and gets the token and the backend is hosted on an API app and validates the token.

When developing we deploy the front-end and backend as needed, often with multiple copies for multiple developers.

The problem is that the B2C app registration requires to add the reply URL manually. Our development domains are generally under https://XXX###.azurewebsites.net. where XXX is a common prefix and ### is some number.

Is there a way to either define the reply URL programmatically (i.e. add it and remove it as we deploy/remove the instance) or to support wildcard reply URLs?

If the above is not possible is there a way to programmatically register a new application with a copy of all configurations of an existing one except the reply URL?

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard redirect URLs are not supported in OAuth2.  See this post: [why are redirect URLs fully qualified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520604/why-is-redirect-url-fully-qualified-in-azure-ad-b2c).

And, unfortunately, we can't manage B2C programmatically.

UserVoice item: [Programmatically manage B2C policies](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20342455-programmatically-manage-b2c-policies)