# Azure B2C accepting different domains in Redirect URIs: Bug or Feature

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When adding Reply URLs in an Azure B2C Application, the UI shows the following information:

> Redirect URIs must all belong to the same domain

And until recently this was enforced by the UI: no way to save a list with multiple different URLs with the exception of `localhost`.

But just today I found out that right now it's possible to add any domain as Reply URL, which is pretty awesome for my use case. Is this going to stay and the info is outdated or is this a bug (which would be a shame, because this makes multi-domain apps a lot easier)?

BTW, it's not just that the list can be saved, the redirects work as one would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the restriction has been removed. But the tip on Azure portal hasn't been updated.

Comment: Is there a blog post or change log by Microsoft where this is mentioned?

Comment: @KennethVanCoppenolle I didn't find one. But I have confirmed this with Azure support engineer.

Comment: Hi ! A bit late at the party ;-) But i'm wondering if all this is still good practice or not ? I'v see somewhere that it got broken lately... And since we are about to use something similar to allow multiple instances of our app on a single app registration, I figured this could come in handy.

our use case: 

dev1.dev.someorg.com
dev2.dev.someorg.com
qa1.dev.someorg.com 

etc.... using a single app registration