# SSO issue for multiple domains with MSAL.js

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I want to single sign on multiple domains i.e. www.a.com and www.b.com using MSAL with Azure B2C.I used local storage as cache location, but single sign on does not work in multiple domains.

Answer (score 1):

For SSO to work the Reply URLs in the app registration must all belong to the same domain. It is not currently possible to reply to multiple domains. For reference, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520604/why-is-redirect-url-fully-qualified-in-azure-ad-b2c).

The portal itself has a note: "Redirect URIs must all belong to the same domain."

[image]

Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no way to achieve this right now in Azure.

I recommend upvoting this [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18421084-allow-redirect-url-s-from-different-domain-s-for) in User Voice for the B2C team to review.

Comment: Hi Marilee, thanks for the comments. Can you tell me is it possible in subdomains?