# How to pass state parameter to signup/signin request from Blazor app utilizing MSAL so the common RedirectUri can use it to determine return URL

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, redirect-uri

I have multiple Azure App-Services using Blazor which all need to Authenticate to Azure AD B2C, but all have different URIs. I have implemented a common `RedirectUri` specified in the Application Registration, which works, except that when I try to use the *state* parameter in the request it is ignored and it appears that MSAL is repurposing it.

I did read somewhere that using MSAL.js it is possible, as MSAL.js supposedly will append the state parameter to the GUID it is using and that it would be presented to the `RedirectUri` as accountState. But that doesn't happen with Blazor driving MSAL.js.

I am currently by-passing MSAL and posting directly to the authenticate endpoint and processing the token myself on return to the app, but I have to give up AuthenticationState (unless I write my own). Not an elegant solution, and seems to me Blazor should accommodate this.

When using MSAL in Blazor WASM, how can I use a common Redirect URI for Azure AD B2C for multiple (read as many) App Services without having to register the return URI in the App Registration for each one, as the App Services are dynamic.

Comment: This is commentary.  Is there a question?

Comment: I thought the question was inferred. When using MSAL in Blazor WASM, how can I use a common Redirect URI for Azure AD B2C for multiple (read as many) App Services without having to register the return URI in the App Registration for each one, as the App Services are dynamic

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you want this instead of registering the additional URIs? This concept is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546311/1690217) and is why the default Blazor implementation overrides your custom `state`. It will also cause issues with your token renewal, unless you have deliberately set long expiry which is itself a security concern.

Comment: There will be hundreds of sites that are created on demand. And the is a limit on how many redirect Uris can be placed on a registration. BTW, thanks for the edit